# JWTToken Generating but not Authorizing and giving 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I am using .NET 8 I want to implement and generate JWT to secure routes and only allow routes to be access by Roles. The problem I am having is no matter what token is generated, whenever I add `[Authorize]` or `[Authorize(Role = <RoleName>)]`, I still get a 404 Not Found error. I'm not sure why.

My end goal is to be able to have user be created but will not have access until given a specific role.

`Program.cs`:

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using TheGospelMission.Configurations;
using TheGospelMission.Data;
using TheGospelMission.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add Service
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// DI for DbContext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<GospelMissionDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySql(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"),
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection"))
    );

    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); // Enable query logging
});

// Jwt Authentication
builder.Services.Configure<JwtConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig"));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => 
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(jwt => 
{
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Secret").Value);

    jwt.SaveToken = true;
    jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Issuer").Value,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Audience").Value,
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };
    jwt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {context.Exception.Message}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});

builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GospelMissionDbContext>();

    
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Default User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

});

// Authorization Policies
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
    // Authorization Policies
    .AddPolicy("OverseerPolicy", policy => policy.RequireRole("Overseer"));


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS refresh is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

// Exception Handling Middleware
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //await next.Invoke();
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log the exception
    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {e.Message}");

    // You can customize the error response here
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"An error occurred: {e.Message}");
    }
});

// Authentication and Authorization
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Map Controllers
// app.MapControllers();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

// Default Route
app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    // Return your landing page content or redirect to a dedicated landing page controller action
    return "Hello World!";
});

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var roleManager =
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

    var roles = new[] {"Overseer", "Assistant Overseer","Group Leader", "Unit Leader" };
    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
            Console.WriteLine($"Role {role} created.");
    }
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var userManager =
        scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();

    string username = "TimmyTurner";
    string firstName = "Timothy";
    string lastName = "Singleton";
    string email = "superadmin@admin.com";
    string gender = "male";
    string password = "Password1!";
    int churchId = 1;

    if (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email) == null)
    {
        var user = new User();
        user.UserName = username;
        user.FirstName = firstName;
        user.LastName = lastName;
        user.Email = email;
        user.Gender = gender;
        user.ChurchId = churchId;

        await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Overseer");
    }
}

app.Run();
```

`AccountController`:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using TheGospelMission.Models;

namespace TheGospelMission.Controllers;

[Route("api/[controller]")] //api/account
[ApiController]
public class AccountController(
    UserManager<User> userManager,
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    ILogger<AccountController> logger) : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager = userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager = roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration = configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<AccountController> _logger = logger;

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel register)
    {
        try
        {
            // validate incoming request
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // check if the email already exist
                var user_exist = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(register.Email);

                if (user_exist != null)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                    {
                        Status = "Failed",
                        Result = false,
                        Errors = new List<string>()
                        {
                            "Email already exist"
                        }
                    });
                }

                // create user
                var new_user = new User()
                {
                    UserName = register.Username,
                    FirstName = register.FirstName,
                    LastName = register.LastName,
                    Email = register.Email,
                    Gender = register.Gender
                };

                var is_created = await _userManager.CreateAsync(new_user, register.Password);

                if (is_created.Succeeded)
                {
                    // generate token
                    // var token = GenerateJwtToken(new_user);

                    return Ok(new AuthResult() 
                    {   Status = "Success", 
                        Message = "User created successfully!",
                        // Token = token
                    });
                }
            
                // Log the details of the failure
                _logger.LogError($"User registration failed: {string.Join(", ", is_created.Errors)}");

                return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                {
                    Errors = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Server Error"
                    },
                    Status = "Failed"
                });
            }
        }    
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log unexpected exceptions
                _logger.LogError($"An unexpected error occurred during user registration: {ex}");
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An unexpected error occurred.");
            }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    [HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel login)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // check if user exist
                var exiting_user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(login.UserName);

                // User not found, return a BadRequest response with an error message
                if (exiting_user == null)
                    return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                        {
                            Status = "Failed",
                            Result = false,
                            Message = "Please Create a user",
                            Errors = new List<string>()
                            {
                                "User doesn't exist"
                            }
                        });
                
                // Check if the provided password is correct
                var isCorrect = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(exiting_user, login.Password);

                if (!isCorrect)
                    // Incorrect password, return a BadRequest response with an error message
                    return BadRequest(new AuthResult()
                    {
                        Status = "Failed",
                        Result = false,
                        Errors = new List<string>()
                            {
                                "Invalid Credentials"
                            }
                    });

                // Password is correct, generate a JWT token
                var jwtToken = GenerateJwtToken(exiting_user);

                // Return a successful response with the JWT token
                return Ok(new AuthResult()
                {
                    Token = jwtToken,
                    Result = true,
                    Status = "Success",
                    Message ="Login was Successful;"
                });
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Log unexpected exceptions
            _logger.LogError($"An unexpected error occurred during user login: {ex}");
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An unexpected error occurred.");
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }

    private string GenerateJwtToken(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            var JwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Secret").Value);

            var configuration = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            var audience = configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Audience").Value;
            var issuer =configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig:Issuer").Value;

            // Get user roles claims
            var roleClaims = GetUserRolesClaims(user);

            //Token descriptor
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new []
                {
                    new Claim("Id", user.Id),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString()),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud, audience ),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, issuer),
                }.Union(roleClaims)),

                NotBefore = DateTime.Now,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };

            var token = JwtTokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var jwtToken = JwtTokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            return jwtToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception for debugging purposes
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Error generating JWT token");
            throw; // Rethrow the exception for higher-level error handling
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Claim> GetUserRolesClaims(User user)
    {
        // Get user roles
        var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;

        // Create claims for each role
        var roleClaims =roles?.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Claim>();

        return roleClaims;
    }
}
```

`AdminController`:

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TheGospelMission.Models;

namespace TheGospelMission.Controllers;

    [Route("api/[controller]")] //api/admin
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "Overseer")]
    //[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

    public class AdminController(UserManager<User> userManager) : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager = userManager;

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Dashboard")]
        public IActionResult Dashboard()
        {
                var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
                var userName = User.Identity.Name;
                var userRoles = User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role).Select(c => c.Value);

                // Log or print information for debugging
                Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {userId}, Username: {userName}, Roles: {string.Join(", ", userRoles)}");

                return Ok("Welcome to the Dashboard");
        }
}
```

Comment: Any possibility the config value for "JwtConfig:Issuer" isn't loading as expected?

Comment: That part i'm not sure. When i add the token into jwt.io i see the issuer within the token. but i have been doing some more playing around and even when I don't have a user i get the same 404 Not found. I believe it something with the** app.UseAuthorization** and **app.UseAuthentication**. but not sure either how to debug those. I just know when i remove them i can access the route. and when I just have [Authorize] on the route it catches error saying i need **app.UseAuthorization**.  this is what i've been trying to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the source codes of `AddIdentity` method:

```
public static IdentityBuilder AddIdentity<TUser, [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicConstructors)] TRole>(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
    where TUser : class
    where TRole : class
{
    // Services used by identity
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
        o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme;
        o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidateAsync<ITwoFactorSecurityStampValidator>
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;
        o.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToReturnUrl = _ => Task.CompletedTask
        };
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    });
```

Your default authenticate scheme would be `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme` instead of `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` .You would failed authentication when you don't specific the scheme in Authorize attribute(`[Authorize]` or `[Authorize(Role = <RoleName>)]`) and be redirected to `"/Account/Login"` which doesn't exists in your app ,then you get 404 error

You could try

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,Roles ="{your role}")]
```

Or register Identity with `AddIdentityCore` method which won't change your default authentication scheme

For your 403 statue code,remove your mapping  here :

```
jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidAudiences = new string[]
            {
               "Audience"
             },
    ValidIssuers = new string[]
            {
               "Issuer"
             },
    IssuerSigningKey = key,

    TokenDecryptionKey = anotherkey,
    //remove you mapping here
    //RoleClaimType = "role"
};
```

Comment: Im trying it with the code you suggested and Im getting this error message An error occurred: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme'. The registered schemes are: Bearer, Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme",...)? but looking at the jwt set up i have those in my program.cs from what i am seeing

Comment: Sorry,it's a typo error ,it should be [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,Roles ="{your role}")]

Comment: ok perfect, I have so many questions now, 1. so because of the way its set up I cant use [Authorize(Roles= <RoleName>)] i have to include the JwtBearerDefaults. WHY. 2. Eventhough now Im not getting the 404 Not Found anymore, regardless if i have a role specified or not both users get 403 forbidden

Comment: For your first question,I've explained in my answer,your default scheme has been changed,here's a document related that would help you understand the concept of DefaultScheme,Authentication scheme,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#defaultscheme

Comment: For your 403 error,it was caused by your mapping,please check what I've updated in my answer

Comment: ok so yes it worked for my user who has the role, but instead of getting 401 for the user who doesnt have the role it still got 403. I do appreciate you patience with me and helping me through this. Im going to try see why it says forbidden for the user without the role instead of given a 401.